# OS X - ln -s on a directory in ~ shows strange behaviour

Tags: macos, unix, symbolic-link, links, ln

I'm currently setting up my new system (OS X) and trying to link `~/Git/` to `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`, so that I can access all my git repositories via 127.0.0.1. However, that doesn't work as expected.

While I was able to symlink other directories:

```
ln -s / ~/Desktop/root
ln -s ~ ~/Desktop/home
```

it just doesn't want to work with my `~/Git` directory:

```
sudo ln -s ~/Git /Library/WebServer/Documents/Git
ln -s ~/Git ~/Desktop/Git
```

The link is created, but it's telling me `The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “Git” can’t be found.` Wherever I place it, the behaviour is always the same. It also seems to be the same with other directories in my home directory (except for the home directory itself).

```
ls -l ~/Desktop
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff   1 Jul  8 08:31 : -> /
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff   4 Jul  9 12:50 Git -> /Users/user/Git
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  29 Jul  8 08:38 wwwroot -> /Library/WebServer/Documents/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  19 Jul  8 08:31 ~ -> /Users/user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally (because the default shell on OSX is bash), tilde (`~`) is expanded to your home directory.  That is documented in the [Bash Reference Manual: Tilde Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html).

However, your directory listing shows that you have created an entry `"~"` in your desktop, either by bypassing the default behavior (quoting, as mentioned in *[How to manually expand a special variable (ex: ~ tilde) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash)*), or due to some *error* finding the actual home-directory.  Since you say this is in *any* directory, it sounds as if (during the account creation), you have moved/renamed things, e.g., a different disk drive, so that bash finds no actual directory at the location where it should.  So you get a literal `"~"`.

Comment: Uhm, to think of it now, I changed the language from German to English. After doing this, I noticed that OS X actually didn't rename the stuff in my home directory. So, when working with the shell, I can access it via the English directory names. However, when working with the Finder, everything is still shown in German. I haven't found the reason for this yet. Could this maybe be the problem? If so, how can I rename this stuff, so my Finder finds the actual directory?

Comment: Nevermind, they're just symlinks I needed to rename... still working in the dark now. Everything is correctly named in English, and the shell does expand `~` to my home directory. Still, it doesn't find the source (which exists, though). It's driving me crazy right now...

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. You were right: the guy who installed OS X for me _did_ change and rename quite many things. I created a completely new user and it works now. Thank you for the essential hint. :)